# Special wedding date and time

Tags: logical-deduction, time

I made this challenge.

Later this decade, Amelia and Jack operates a restaurant where they serve a lot of tasty meals and delicious **product**. Recently, their income from the restaurant is **triple** more than the past couple days because the restaurant is now open for whole day in a **week**. They know that this is result of **a power of** effort.

Because of that, they inquired a events manager and the **couple** said that the wedding date is one day before weekend.

They write the date as this:

$YYYY/DD/MM$, where $y$ is a four digit number, $dd$ is any digit from $1-31$(leading zeroes are allowed, example: $01$), $M$ is any month from January to September.

Their wedding time is scheduled to start at  **a week** before the midnight of weekend and **dozens** of egg their ordered delivered after a few **minutes**.

So the wedding time is like this:

$hh:mm$, where $hh$ is hour and $mm$ is minutes.

When is the wedding day, what is the day of their wedding day and what time is start of their wedding?

Hint:

- the year is between the 4th and 10th year of a decade and the year is any year in the current century.
- Couple is raised to the **product** of **week** and **triple**.

Comment: we'll need some more hints here, I think.. :) "product = triple week to the power of couple", does this refer to (3x7)^2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date is

> 2097/15/02

because

> **Couple** (2) raised to the **product** of **triple week** = `2^(3*7)` = 2097152
> As specified by "said that the wedding date is one day before weekend", [this date is a friday](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2097)

I think (not entirely sure) that the time is

> 17:12

because

> "**a week** before midnight" = `24-7` = 17
> "and **dozens minutes**" = 12
> Alternatively we could ignore "midnight" because it is not marked bold and end up with `7:12`

Comment: How do you get 10 from dozens?

Comment: @fljx good question :) fixed now

Comment: Given that "dozens" is plural, I'd have made that 24 instead of 12.